# Check https server status with specific port and self-signed certification

Tags: php

I am running PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu 18.04, Apache2.

---

What I want is simple : check server status, show if online or offline.

Server not responds if it is under http.(Connection always have to be https)

Server's certification is self-signed.

---

I'll say it is https://servername:10010/

The codes I tried are those :

```
$host = 'https://servername';
if($socket =@ fsockopen($host, 10010, $errno, $errstr, 10)) {
echo 'online!';
fclose($socket);
} else {
echo 'offline.';
}
```

and

```
$host = 'ssl://servername';
if($socket =@ fsockopen($host, 10010, $errno, $errstr, 10)) {
echo 'online!';
fclose($socket);
} else {
echo 'offline.';
}
```

and

```
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';
$request = new HTTP_Request2('https://servername:10010/', HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
$request->setConfig(array(
    'ssl_verify_peer'   => FALSE,
    'ssl_verify_host'   => FALSE
));
try {
    $response = $request->send();    
    if (200 == $response->getStatus()) {
  //echo $response->getBody();//Get content of page
var_dump($response->getStatus());
    } else {
echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .$response->getReasonPhrase();
    }
} catch (HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

and

```
$data = "";
$timeout = "1";
$services = array();
$services[] = array("port" => "10010", "service" => "blabla", "ip" => "https://servername") ;
$data .= "";
foreach ($services  as $service) {
    if($service['ip']==""){
       $service['ip'] = "localhost";
    }
    $fp = @fsockopen($service['ip'], $service['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
    if (!$fp) {
        $data .= "Off";
      //fclose($fp);
    } else {
        $data .= "On";
    }
}
echo $data;
```

None of theese worked.

Second One's Error (I saw) was Connection timed out. (BTW server is up)

Comment: Have you tried `CURL`  .  Besides that SSL typically runs on port 443  not 10010, but with CURL you can use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 10010);` see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried plain old CURL:

Taken from this answer

[PHP CURL & HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https)

But modified for the PORT:

```
/**
 * Get a web file (HTML, XHTML, XML, image, etc.) from a URL.  Return an
 * array containing the HTTP server response header fields and content.
 */
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,     // Disabled SSL Cert checks for self singed certs.
        CURLOPT_PORT           => 10010     // Port --- added this
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```

Not sure if it will work.  But this `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` disables the verification on the certificate, which can be useful when testing against Self singed certs.

See this answer how to fix that (properly verify the cert):

[Verifying SSL certificate failing with Kohana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808312/verifying-ssl-certificate-failing-with-kohana)

I would have done it as a duplicate, but this question is not specific to CURL, this is just an option that wasn't mentioned as being attempted.

Hope it works for you!

**UPDATE**

Seeing as all your PHP attempts failed, I think it could be an issue with a firewall blocking that port..

As I said in the comments:

> Are you trying this script from the same computer, or is it on a server, you could have a firewall issue on a server that blocks that port. Personally I don't think it's PHP.

Comment: Nope, it didn't worked for me. HTTP Status code was 524 (timeout) when I tried.

Comment: Yes, I even can access by browser.

Comment: Are you trying this script from the same computer, or is it on a server, you could have a firewall issue on a server that blocks that port.  Personally I don't think it's PHP.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. found some firewall issue blocking ports I've tried. Thanks.

Comment: Kool!  I'll add it to the answer.