# Is it possible to run symfony2 development server with ssl connection?

Tags: symfony, https

I am developing my new project in symfony 2 in built-in Symfony2 sever (`app/console server:run`). Is it possible to run my website with https on this server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `php app/console server:run` use the [PHP built-in web server](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) that was designed to aid application development and isn't supposed to support SSL, just plain HTTP requests.

You can try to use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946566/3059764

Answer (score 8):

now it is possible using the symfony cli, you can install a ssl certificate

```
symfony server:ca:install
```

https://symfony.com/blog/local-web-server-reloaded-for-symfony-apps

To install symfony client if you are on a Mac run:

```
curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
```

Otherwise check this link for other OS: https://symfony.com/download

Comment: I dont have symfony in my terminal