# what should i have to use start slim3 application on https

Tags: php, slim-3

using below command my application run on http url and url will be `http://localhost:8080`

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php
```

how to enable listening on https and url will be `https://localhost:8080`

is there any special command to execute it on `https`
 `php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php`

Comment: HTTPS is not supported. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946486/openssl-not-working-with-php-built-in-webserver

Comment: use virtual host

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an SSL certificate for lokalhost and use ning or apache as a frontend.

see:

- [creating SSL cetrificate](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/)
- [apache settings](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html)
- [nginx settings](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)