# Running Apache HTTP on SSL with

Tags: apache, https, jboss

I have successfully implemented the two different jboss 5 instaces with Apache HTTP Server and can access the application through the HTTP server (i.e. `http://localhost:8089`) where my http server is listening on port 8089 This was the smooth case. But when talking about HTTP Secured layer have enabled the Apache HTTP SSL by following the steps provided on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-create-https-for-localhost-apache) and on default secure port (i.e. 443) now i can access the HTTP Server from secure layer by url: `https://localhost/`. But when i hit my jboss application, I ended up with following error in browser:

Not Found

The requested URL /myApp was not found on this server.

can anyone let me know how to deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the vhost setting for https ?

Comment: Have you configured the respective ProxyPass directives for your 'myApp' in the SSL virtualhost? As asked by Ratish, could you provide the relevant part of your vhost configuration?

Comment: Ratish, following are my vhosts settings found in the file: APACHE_HOME/conf/extras/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: PART - I
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.khi.systemsltd.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host.khi.systemsltd.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.khi.systemsltd.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.khi.systemsltd.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.khi.systemsltd.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.khi.systemsltd.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

Comment: PART - II

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.khi.systemsltd.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host2.khi.systemsltd.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.khi.systemsltd.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.khi.systemsltd.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.khi.systemsltd.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>