# Enabling OpenSSL in WAMP

Tags: openssl, wampserver

I installed the latest WAMP (from [wampserver.com](http://wampserver.com)) today on my Windows 7 computer.

I have enabled SSL in `PHP > PHP Extensions > php_openssl`

And `Apache > Apache Modules > open_ssl`

But when I try to access anything with https:// I get "Problem Loading Page". The apache_error.log says

```
[Thu Jun 27 16:25:08.622056 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4812:tid 356] AH01882: Init: this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013, version currently loaded is OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013) - may result in undefined or erroneous behavior


[Thu Jun 27 16:25:08.973076 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4812:tid 356] AH01882: Init: this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013, version currently loaded is OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013) - may result in undefined or erroneous behavior


[Thu Jun 27 16:25:09.356098 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4812:tid 356] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]


[Thu Jun 27 16:25:09.365099 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4812:tid 356] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1d PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Thu Jun 27 16:25:09.365099 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4812:tid 356] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37

[Thu Jun 27 16:25:09.365099 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4812:tid 356] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'

[Thu Jun 27 16:25:09.366099 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4812:tid 356] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3452

[Thu Jun 27 16:25:09.664116 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 3452:tid 248] AH01882: Init: this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013, version currently loaded is OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013) - may result in undefined or erroneous behavior

[Thu Jun 27 16:25:09.954132 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 3452:tid 248] AH01882: Init: this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013, version currently loaded is OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013) - may result in undefined or erroneous behavior

[Thu Jun 27 16:25:10.327154 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 3452:tid 248] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]


[Thu Jun 27 16:25:10.339154 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3452:tid 248] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I allow HTTPS for Apache on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wampserver with apache 2.4.4 released with wrong openssl files. All the things to do is: download and install the 1.0.1e openssl from here: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Then find these files in the installed directory:

bin\openssl.cfg

bin\libeay32.dll

bin\ssleay32.dll

bin\openssl.exe

Stop the apache server.
at first, save a BACKUP of them. Then overright these files in your apache directory:

conf\openssl.cnf->rename the cfg here

bin\libeay32.dll

bin\ssleay32.dll

bin\openssl.exe

Restart the server. Solved.

Comment: I dont know how or why but this just now made my server crash.

Comment: @George D's suggestion worked for me. This, unfortunately, didn't. My server didn't crash though

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: 1.0.1e no longer there !

Answer (score 37):

The path to php.ini [in case you want that for composer] is C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.x\php.ini . This file is not the same as the one that you have if you navigate through the Wamp tray icon

Go there and remove the semicolon as @milesstewart88 says

Comment: If you're facing this problem with Composer, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 25):

Just uncomment your openssl extension in your php.ini file.

Eg. `;extension=php_openssl.dll`

Remove the semicolon so it's like this.

`extension=php_openssl.dll`

That should work; it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

On a **Wampserver** with **Apache 2.4.4** and this worked for me:
Assuming you already created a dir with SSL key and certificate for example at: `c:/wamp/OpenSSL`

uncomment in **httpd.conf**:

```
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so  
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so  
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so  
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
</IfModule>
```

edit in **httpd-ssl.conf**:

```
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:c:/wamp/OpenSSL/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"  

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www" 
    ServerName localhost:443
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log"
    SSLCertificateFile "c:/wamp/OpenSSL/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/wamp/OpenSSL/certs/server.key"
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/ssl_request.log" \
      "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

uncomment in **php.ini**: `extension=php_openssl.dll`

Answer (score 1):

See How I did manage this..

```
uncomment below line from <WEBroot>/bin/apache/Apache2.x/conf/httpd.conf

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

           &

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Place your certificates & key on a separate folder say "wwwssl"

```
AND GOT TO <WEBroot>/bin/apache/Apache2.x/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Create a virtual host for desired server see eg: below

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "<WEBroot>/www/"
    ServerName localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "<WEBroot>/wwwssl/webserver.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "<WEBroot>/wwwssl/webserver.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like milesstewart88 said - uncoment line extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini file.

Doing that from wamp menu wont work - which can misslead from real problem.