# i have error connect socket

Tags: php, sockets, smtp, gmail

I install osticket on server (php open source program for control project)
I want to send email after create ticket but I can not configure it
I enable smtp configuration

```
host smtp:smtp.gmail.com
port:465
Authentication required: yes
email addres: my gmail account
pass: my gmail pass
username: my gmail account
```

but I have error after save configuration

```
Failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Permission denied (code: -1, response
```

[**php.ini**](http://tbf.me/a/UiK8g)

Comment: do you have permission to connect to remote host?

Comment: Also you need to have SSL enabled and use it.  Check this page out: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Comment: @Dylan i check this page ,i find this paragraph:Did you enable SSL for the SMTP server? and in this paragraph there was a link for configure but this link was about IMAP and pop, whoever i enable its but i have error maybe i must change php.ini can u help?

Comment: In your PHP .ini enable: php_openssl.dll. You'll also need to specify that you're using SSL in your SMTP configuration.

Comment: @Dylan i find php.ini in server(/etc/php.ini) but there are not any line about php_openssl.dll i left my  php.ini of server for u,but i could find this line in php in mycopsuet(window and wampserver)

Comment: @maryam You might have to install an "addon" or "package"... I believe they're available through the wampserver site.  I apologize that I can't be of more help.

Comment: @Dylan did you see my php.ini , i left it bottom of my question , why Why is php.ini different.

Comment: I didn't see it... you can check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354788/enabling-openssl-in-wamp but I am not 100% sure the only issue is the SSL.