# Errors when trying to use PHPMail via the Gmail servers

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I'm trying to set up authentication emails for my website.  I don't need anything fancy or secure, but I'm having massive troubles trying to get this to work.

Here is my PHP

```
function emailconfirmation($temppass, $emailaddress) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = 'myEmail@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'myGmailPassword';
    $mail->SetFrom('myEmail@gmail.com');
    $mail->AddAddress($emailaddress);
    $mail->Subject = 'Test';
    $mail->Body    = 'test authentication key: ' . $temppass;
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        return 'Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is the error it keeps spitting out

```
2013-09-14 22:43:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mydomain.com 2013-09-14 22:43:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in C:\wamp\bin\php\includes\PHPMailer-master\class.smtp.php on line 274
2013-09-14 22:43:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2013-09-14 22:43:13  SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Any help that you guys can provide would be great.  FYI, I've allowed the port 587 through my firewall, and the email I'm sending to is not the same as the one I'm sending from.  Thanks!

---

EDIT:
Seriously, nobody?  This is really getting on my nerves

Comment: It looks like you are missing SSL support in your PHP installation. Without it you won't have success, even if you don't think you need security.

Comment: okay, so I uncommented extension=php_openssl.dll in my php.ini because of some tips on how to install SSL.  Now there is no error, but the page just hangs

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable OpenSSL in your WAMP setup.

I see you uncommented this line: `extension=php_openssl.dll` which is good, but apparently Wampserver with apache 2.4.4 released with wrong OpenSSL files!

Per [this other StackOverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354788/enabling-openssl-in-wamp) you should [Download an install the Win32 OpenSSL files](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)  yourself.

Then *stop WAMP*, take these files from your newly installed OpenSSL directory:

```
bin\openssl.cfg
bin\libeay32.dll
bin\ssleay32.dll
bin\openssl.exe
```

copy them over these files in your WAMP/Apache directory:

```
conf\openssl.cnf (rename the openssl.cfg file to openssl.cnf to overwrite this)
bin\libeay32.dll
bin\ssleay32.dll
bin\openssl.exe
```

Finally, *Start WAMP*.