# php composer.phar update symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, wamp

I am starting with Symfony2 I try to install the bundle (fosuserbundle) and when I execute the command (php composer.phar update) the console shows me this message:

> you must enable the openssl extension to download files via https
>   Symfony2

I enabled the openssl in php extentions; eliminate (;) before the php_openssl in fichers `php.ini`, `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` ... I do all and the same message (I'm really tired of searching)

I use WampServer Version 2.4

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out this [Enabling OpenSSL in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354788/enabling-openssl-in-wamp)

What version of WAMP are you running? Have you run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and looked for openssl on the page?

**Edit** haha long day, thanks RiggsFolly.

Comment: I use WampServer Version 2.4 2.2e

Comment: @Braunson Just a note to anybody else reading this, the function is `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 0):

In WAMPServer there are 2 php.ini files.

One in the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.x\bin` folder which is used when you run PHP on your website ( that the file that is edited when you use the wampmanager menus to edit php.ini) and one in the `\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y` folder.

When you are running PHP CLI ( Command Line Interface ) as you are when you execute php from the command line, the the php.exe file uses the ini file locatied in `\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y\php.ini`. You have to edit this file manually, it is not accessible from the wampmanager menu system.

So edit  `\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y\php.ini` and in that file remove the comment `;` from the `php_openssl.dll` line, and any other extensions that you may be using when you run php in CLI mode.