# OpenSSL Header Version != OpenSSL Library Version affecting HTTP/2 for APNS

Tags: php, apache, curl, openssl, wamp

i have this weird combo on my openSSL.

My command prompt `openssl version` returns the library version -> OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016

where my php curl call -> `echo "openssl version text: " . OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT . "\n";` returns the header version: openssl version text: OpenSSL 1.0.1t 3 May 2016

i wonder how can i updated the OpenSSL Header version as i need 1.0.2 in order for the APNS to work as i'm still getting

`HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes: 504f5354202f332f6465766963652f613433646466376235`

i'm using WAMP
Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) 
PHP/5.6.16

[image]

Comment: Basically its nothing to worry about

Comment: @RiggsFolly unfortunately i need it updated. please see my updated question

Comment: I think you will need to upgrade your version of PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly thats the latest WAMP available...

Comment: Also see [How to install: OpenSSL + WAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9320529) and [Enabling OpenSSL in WAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17718557/608639). OpenSSL 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 are *supposed* to be binary compatible, so you may be able to swap-in new DLLs.

Comment: @jww thanks! i swap-in the new DLLs i download in apache and PHP, but it still showing 1.01t :/

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this issue only by upgrading your PHP version OR you can also reinstall PHP/5.6.16. after that your both Openssl version will be same.

I have also faced this issue and after spending lots of time I found this solution.

Comment: how would u do that in WAMP?

Comment: @Desmond If it is possible then reinstall WAMP. Otherwise Please Visit these URLs to Upgrade PHP into wamp. 1) http://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in/2015/06/how-to-upgrade-php-53-to-php-54-in-wamp-server-in-window7.html  2)  http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,116940,117978#msg-117978  3)  http://superuser.com/questions/335941/how-to-add-new-php-version-to-wamp/569472

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same basic issue and have reinstalled php 5.6 to no effect. I now have a library version of 1.0.1p and a header version of 1.0.2j. I've removed openssl, mod_php, apache 2.4, and php 5.6 and reinstalled them all which updated the header version to 1.0.2j but not the library version.

I don't think this is as simple as just reinstalling php 5.6, at least not on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I had to upgrade openSSL to 1.1+

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of old Apache/HTTPD. I rebuilt PHP with new libcurl & openssl - in command line everything seemed to be OK, but in web-server-mode - used to get old version of OpenSSL. I spent a few hours dancing around - finally I got to recompile Apache also - and that helped me out! Because Apache loaded old libss.so BEFORE php was started. Pay attention on that.