# facebook app doesn't connect to local server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

i have a ready web application at my local server

```
http://192.168.100.1/public/MAYUR/fbtest/
```

Now i have created a FB app and want to display my local server app via fb. I have everything set up on FB . However as soon as i click on the Play Game link on my app page it gives the following error message-

```
The webpage at https://192.168.100.1/public/MAYUR/fbtest/?fb_source=appcenter&fb_appcenter=1 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error.
```

I have the following App Settings-

```
Site URL - http://192.168.100.1/public/MAYUR/fbtest/index.php

Canvas URL - https://192.168.100.1/public/MAYUR/fbtest/

Secure Canvas URL - https://192.168.100.1/public/MAYUR/fbtest/
```

I read in tutorials that it doesn't matter if the the site is hosted locally or online as iframe can source the contents locally too.

Any idea what could be reason for the issue? This is my first FB app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled SSL for your localhost? Is the link: `https://192.168.100.1/public/MAYUR/fbtest/` working in the browser?

If not , please configure your apache first and then try— [How do I allow HTTPS for Apache on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-create-https-for-localhost-apache)

OR, if you are up just for the testing purpose, you can leave the `Secure canvas url` as blank, enable the `Sandbox Mode`, adn test your application

Comment: thanks dude...!! Worked fine..It never occurred to me that SSL is not allowed on my local server..