# Facebook PHP SDK localhost as secure server (SSL)

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

We develop local apps that redirect to a secure web host which then sends the relevant FB app info to our FB app which in turn redirects back to our web server which redirects back to our local app. The local app stores the relevant FB user info so that user interaction is then posted to FB as per their approval. Everything works perfectly except for our latest project.

Our latest project running in Dubai is having latency issues between FB, the web server and our localhost on its return from the FB app authorisation. When the PHP script execution time was set to 30 seconds the redirect would timeout. We have increased this execution duration and the app works again but the wait is not ideal as ppl are queued in malls waiting to try out the activation.

I see it is possible to setup SSL on the localhost server as per: [How do I allow HTTPS for Apache on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-create-https-for-localhost-apache)

**So my question is: Would FB allow this SSL connection or would the certificate have to come from an authority on a certified web server?**

I was thinking of using the localhost WAMP server as the web server aswell and setting up its own OpenSSL to try reduce the latency issues.

**I never built the original application so does the FB PHP SDK even need to be hosted on a secure site?**

Comment: Facebook only connects to your server when you use Open Graph objects that it has to scrape, or real time updates. Everything else just happens within the user’s browser … and the browser will of course complain when the SSL certificate is not “kosher”.