# kohana site on localhost is not working with https://

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, kohana

I have a website written with kohana. I want to test it if its working with ssl. I have ssl module installed (ubuntu default ssl configuration). The problem is: all my websites using kohana on localhost (apache) not working with https:// (only main pages are working for example: "https:localhost/kohanasite" is working, but if i give controller and action it is not working, but if i ad index.php before controler and action it is working again). Other websites (not written with kohana) are working properly. My htaccess is as follows:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /sitename/

Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All

RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]

php_value allow_url_fopen on
php_value allow_url_include 1

Plese help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new Apache configuration for the https sites too. Enable the module is not enough. [How do I allow HTTPS for Apache on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost)

Comment: Yes. I edited default-ssl.conf and set directory allw rewriting to all. It is working now thanks.