# How to display the contents of the server in HTTPS protocol

Tags: apache, http, https, server

I'm using Apache HTTP server, I'm able to display the contents of the server (through browser) in HTTP protocol but not possible for displaying the same contents in HTTPS protocol. I also tried changing the listening port from 80XX to 443. But nothing positive happened. Any thing (specific  to HTTPS protocol) should be done in order to make it open in browser ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost

Comment: Thanks a lot !! it works for me.

Also this link will be more useful 

http://rubayathasan.com/tutorial/apache-ssl-on-windows/#comment-1253636

Comment: @smartmeta: In addition, If i try to retrieve the response code (using JAVA) for an HTTPS connection im getting an exception like below :



javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target