# Telegram Chatbot with xammp throws Error

Tags: php, xampp, telegram-bot

Some time ago I started creating my own telegram-bot. I've some simple code and set up a project via composer. I plan to use xampp as a Server-software. I've created a directory in the `C:\xampp\htdocs` directory and called it `bot`. Inside the directory there is my code, including the `composer.json` and `vendor/` directory.

When I run the apache server and open http://localhost/bot/main.php (which is the main-document), I get the following error:

**Output of http://localhost/bot/main.php:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Telegram\Bot\Exceptions\TelegramSDKException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bot\vendor\irazasyed\telegram-bot-sdk\src\HttpClients\GuzzleHttpClient.php:114 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bot\vendor\irazasyed\telegram-bot-sdk\src\TelegramClient.php(117): Telegram\Bot\HttpClients\GuzzleHttpClient->send('https://api.tel...', 'POST', Array, Array, 60, false, 10) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\bot\vendor\irazasyed\telegram-bot-sdk\src\Api.php(1014): Telegram\Bot\TelegramClient->sendRequest(Object(Telegram\Bot\TelegramRequest)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\bot\vendor\irazasyed\telegram-bot-sdk\src\Api.php(958): Telegram\Bot\Api->sendRequest('POST', 'getMe', Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\bot\vendor\irazasyed\telegram-bot-sdk\src\Api.php(269): Telegram\Bot\Api->post('getMe') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\bot\main.php(20): Telegram\Bot\Api->getMe() #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bot\vendor\irazasyed\telegram-bot-sdk\src\HttpClients\GuzzleHttpClient.php on line 114

I don't know what exactly the problem is, it seems to be an issue with a self-signed certificate, but I don't get what is the explicit problem and how to fix it.

I hope you can help me with an answer here.

Comment: Telegram bots work over SSL (`https`). You `localhost` definitely doesn't support it.

Comment: @u_mulder How do i tell xampp to use https then?

Comment: read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost

Comment: @LifeTimeProgrammer This looks good, I'll try this solution.

Comment: @LifeTimeProgrammer I've tried the solution you posted a link to, during completing the instructions there were no errors. But when I open https://localhost/bot/main.php I get an 404 Error, and when I open https://localhost/main.php (just without the subdirectory) I get the same error message as before.

Comment: check your port bcz some other services may run. @TobiasF.

Comment: @LifeTimeProgrammer I've cheked if any other service is using Port 80 or 443 using resmon.exe, but there is no other service/process which uses port 80 and/or 443.

Comment: run some other php files and check it. its worked or not @TobiasF.

Comment: I tried to run some other php files, everything went well and no errors occured. The reason why I got an 404 Error was I choosed the wrong directory in the httpdssl.conf, this is now fixed. @LifeTimeProgrammer

Comment: :( okay keep going

Comment: I asked my Instructor at work, he told me it's probably an clientside-issue, it seems my server isn't accepting the certificates provided/ used by Telegram, so I have to tell curl to accept all ssl certificates, no matter if they are trusted or not. Now I try to figure out where in the Code I have to modify something, I hope it works this time.

Comment: Well, finally i decided to use the Google AppEngine instead, so i don't have to worry about untrusted certificates and so on. It's now running fine. @LifeTimeProgrammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I finally decided to switch to the GoogleAppEngine, so I don't have to worry about untrusted certificates and so on, now everything is working fine. But thanks for your help anyway (especially @LifeTimeProgrammer).

Answer (score 0):

go to the file \vendor\irazasyed\telegram-bot-sdk\src\HttpClients\GuzzleHttpClient.php
Changing the setting

```
   public function __construct(Client $client = null)
{
 $this->client = $client ?: new Client();
}
```

on

```
    public function __construct(Client $client = null)
{
$this->client = $client ?: new Client(['verify' => false ]);
}
```

Comment: This is not particulary helpful almost 6 years after this problem appeared and I found a solution for myself. Just needlessly bumps this question up :)

Comment: Please never edit vendor files because after any update or install your loose your changes !