# Support SSL with Apache2 VirtualHost port proxy?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

We have a VirtualHost configured likeso:

```
<VirtualHost *:4567>
  SSLEngine on
  <Directory "/var/www/html/proso/html">
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/site
</VirtualHost>
```

If we go to `http://site:4567` everything works. If we use `https://site:4567` we get `this site can’t provide a secure connection`.
After reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost) and following each step carefully, there is still an error. How do you ssl enable the port with a VirtualHost for both secure and normal communication?

Comment: an ssl-handshake can't be optional on a single port. Maybe it's a security logic.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought.