# Shopify app developement redirection URL callback

Tags: authentication, redirect, shopify-app

I am working on the Shopify app development. Right now I am working on my local system and try to connect this with the localhost.

Shopify auth is working fine but I have faced problems in redirection URL callback function. It always returns with an https request. I have mentioned redirect URL with http://localhost/appname/callback.

Does Shopify app only work on https?

Please let me know if anyone has knowledge of the Shopify app.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, if you are not checking webhooks you can run it on localhost.

I just think callback address is wrong. Check on which port you are running, for me running rails application that would be http://localhost:3000/appname/callback

Answer (score 1):

Yes Shopify app works only on HTTPS. while installing you can manually replace htpps with http or you can setup SSL in your localhost.

Below post might help.

[How do I allow HTTPS for Apache on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost)

But This is not going to work for web-hooks.to make it working for webhooks, you need to create public url that expose your local web server.

you can do this using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Below post Can help you to setup ngrok

https://support.chargebee.com/support/discussions/topics/26214

Answer (score 1):

1. localhost not supporting. you should use ngrok for test app.
2. use HTTP link instead of HTTP.

after this your issue will be fixed

Comment: 2. you mean https, please edit it.

Answer (score 0):

use shopify cli, it is super helpful for this. It includes ngrok helpers that will auto generate the new https url and update the URL on run in your shopify app detail when in dev mode.