# how to make localhost http to https

Tags: https, localhost, ssl-certificate, apache2, ca

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zdl68h_N2lc I followed this link. I tried to make HTTP to HTTPS  in local apache and I got it has <strike>https</strike>://localhost but I want to make https://localhost. when I enter this address its says un-secure connection. but I want to enter this address without any warning. 
And I need to know how to generate CA certificate in local is there is possible in local.

is there any other link or tutorial is there suggest me.

Comment: See the full video here https://youtu.be/D5IqDcHyXSQ

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate SSL cert file by configuring like openssl in Apache. Then you have to configure in httpd.conf file.
You can find these step by step in the following link.
[How do I allow HTTPS for Apache on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost)