# I am having an issue with my HTTP client in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I run my HTTP client it gives me SSL error

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("localhost, 8000)
conn.request("GET","/Test File.txt")
```

Comment: Where is your problem or error?

Comment: Please [edit] your title into something less generic.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `localhost` isn't configured with `HTTPS`. You can resolve this by using `HTTPConnection` client.

Try this:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost, 8000)
conn.request("GET","/Test File.txt")
```

If you would like to set up `HTTPS` on your localhost, you can see this [Stackoverflow Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a **HTTPSConnection** `HTTP ->S<- Connection` (notice the **S** in the class identifier) which is a SSL connection. Is the localhost:8000 a SSL certified server? If not you might either want to use HTTPConnection instead or make sure your configure your server as an SSL server.